# optional Descriptor component in cap-file in JavaCard Spec 2.2.2 and below

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

researching in the JCVM specification while trying to decompile a capfile, the following question came to my mind:

The Descriptor Component (6.13) says:

> The Descriptor Component provides sufficient information to parse and verify all
>   elements of the CAP file. It references, and therefore describes, elements in the
>   Constant Pool Component (Section 6.7, “Constant Pool Component” on page 6-14),
>   Class Component (Section 6.8, “Class Component” on page 6-21), Method
>   Component (Section 6.9, “Method Component” on page 6-35), and Static Field
>   Component (Section 6.10, “Static Field Component” on page 6-41). No components
>   in the CAP file reference the Descriptor Component.

The Component Model (6.1) says:

> A complete
>   CAP file must contain all of the required components specified in this chapter. Three
>   components are optional: the Applet Component (Section 6.5, “Applet Component”
>   on page 6-12), Export Component (Section 6.12, “Export Component” on page 6-47),
>   and Debug Component (Section 6.14, “Debug Component” on page 6-57).

Yet it says in Installation (6.2):

> COMPONENT_Descriptor (optional)

And I havent observed the Descriptor component in the Global Platform Load for Load commands! So the question arises what the descriptor is actually used for and why it is not neccesary for the applet to work on-card?
In contrary, JCVM spec 3.0.1 and greater don't list the descriptzor compnent as optional.

Answer (score 2):

> And I havent observed the Descriptor component in the Global Platform
>   Load for Load commands! So the question arises what the descriptor is
>   actually used for and why it is not neccesary for the applet to work
>   on-card?

The `Descriptor.cap` component provides the information for parsing and verification of other elements in the CAP file. So, the Descriptor.cap component is needed for byte code verification (BCV), which is done off-card and has no importance for card operations. It references and points to information for different CAP file components, but no component (mandatory ones) points to Descriptor component. So, there is no need to load this component on the card. Hence, you don't see it in `Global Platform [Load] commands.`

As defined in the below JCVM spec 3.0.5 specification.

*The Descriptor Component provides sufficient information to parse and verify all elements of the CAP
file. It references, and therefore describes, elements in the Constant Pool Component (6.8 Constant Pool
Component), Class Component (6.9 Class Component), Method Component (6.10 Method Component),
and Static Field Component (6.11 Static Field Component). No components in the CAP file reference the
Descriptor Component.*

> In contrary, JCVM spec 3.0.1 and greater don't list the descriptzor
>   compnent as optional.

They describe `Descriptor.cap` as `optional` in the installation order of CAP file component in the following JCVM spec 3.0.5 (Section 6.3). Although not the same specification, but its hard to say why they miss to mention this in the specification you mentioned.

https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/JCVMS/JCVMS.pdf

Comment: thanks for your comment, I'm starting to uinderstand more points of it. Additional question: A lot of information is missing without the descriptor component, like accessmodifiers(public, private), so these are only checked offcard by the BCV? This also means that a lot of information is lost to reverse-engineer the capfile without a descriptor component, as I'm missing for example the byte code length and access modifiers of methods etc? The normalizer.bat from the SDK is requiring the descriptor component...

Comment: Uh, that would make sense. The idea of the .cap file is lower code size, and the jumps in the byte code can just jump to a specific location - you don't need the byte code size for that. And you have the firewall to take care of the access conditions.

Comment: Descriptor component is used by BCV so far, so that make sense.

Comment: do you think there is any feasible way to decompile a cap without descriptor component to class files?